# Dynamic URL passing in web crawler packages using Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

I am working on building a web scraper using Python to make my job easy. I did some searching and I found that the selenium, beautiful soap and scraps packages helps accomplish just that. My need is a little different. Let me illustrate.

```
class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://blog.scrapinghub.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.css('h2.entry-title'):
            yield {'title': title.css('a ::text').extract_first()}

        next_page = response.css('div.prev-post > a ::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

Here is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish

I don't want to HAVE to TYPE in the URL as the argument. I want to be able to EXTRACT it from a cell value in an excel sheet.

Comment: The product described at https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/ might be what you need.